# How can I check for eof in Perl?

Tags: perl, eof

So I have a bit of problem figuring what Perl does in the following case:

```
while(1){
$inputLine=<STDIN>

#parse $inputLine below
#BUT FIRST, I need to check if $inputLine = EOF

}
```

before I get the obvious answer of using `while(<>){}`, let me say that there is a very strong reason that I have to do the above (basically setting up an alarm to interrupt blocking and I didnt want that code to clutter the example).

Is there someway to compare `$inputLine == undef` (as I think that is what STDIN returns at the end).

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your loop, use

```
last unless defined $inputLine;
```

From the [perlfunc documentation on `defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html):

> **defined EXPR**
>   **defined**
>
> Returns a Boolean value telling whether EXPR has a value other than the undefined value [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html). If EXPR is not present, `$_` will be checked.
>
> Many operations return [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) to indicate failure, end of file, system error, uninitialized variable, and other exceptional conditions. This function allows you to distinguish [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) from other values. (A simple Boolean test will not distinguish among [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html), zero, the empty string, and `"0"`, which are all equally false.) Note that since [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) is a valid scalar, its presence doesn't necessarily indicate an exceptional condition: [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) returns [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) when its argument is an empty array, or when the element to return happens to be [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html).

Comment: Thank you. I am new to perl, but I am getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
defined($inputLine)
```

---

Also, see the [4 argument version of the `select` function](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#select) for an alternative way to read from a filehandle without blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*eof*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) on the filehandle. *eof* will return 1 if the next read on FILEHANDLE is an EOF.

Comment: From the eof documentation: "(Note that this function actually reads a character and then 'ungetc's it, so isn't very useful in an interactive context.)" The OP is reading from STDIN, i.e., in an interactive context.

Comment: Ah, I just fixated on the *eof*. On further read, I also noticed that it says you almost never need to use *eof* since you can just look for the *undef*. Funny - I know I've used eof a few times. But I guess TMTOWTDI ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following will have problems with input files that have lines which only have a line feed or as in the case that was giving me problems a FF at the beginning of some lines (Form Feed - the file was the output from a program developed at the end of the 70s and still has formatting for a line printer and is still in FORTRAN - I do miss the wide continous paper for drawing flow diagrams on the back).

```
open (SIMFIL, "<", 'InputFileName') or die "Can´t open InputFileName\n" ;
open (EXTRDATS, ">>", 'OutputFileName' ) or die "Can´t open OutputFileName\n";
$Simfilline = "";
while (<SIMFIL>) {
    $Simfilline = <SIMFIL>;
    print EXTRDATS $Simfilline;
    $Simfilline = <SIMFIL>;
    print EXTRDATS $Simfilline;
    }
close SIMFIL;
close EXTRDATS;
```

`
The following is when eof comes in handy - the expression: "while ()" can return false under conditions other than the end of the file.

```
open (SIMFIL, "<", 'InputFileName') or die "Can´t open InputFileName\n" ;
open (EXTRDATS, ">>", 'OutputFileName' ) or die "Can´t open OutputFileName\n";
$Simfilline = "";
while (!eof SIMFIL) {
    $Simfilline = <SIMFIL>;
    print EXTRDATS $Simfilline;
    $Simfilline = <SIMFIL>;
    print EXTRDATS $Simfilline;
    }
close SIMFIL;
close EXTRDATS;
```

This last code fragment appears to duplicate the input file exactly.